# Need to parse the string for the key:object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
var url = '{access=Свободный, superviser=Ромашкина Яна Витальевна, Spname=Классы Э-2, Э-3, Э-4, name=Эмоции и новая политическая культура, format=Дискуссия, project=Школа эмоционального здоровья, finishDate=09.ноя.2021 22:45, href=Doc?k=Ev&id=d50ed0941c79cf06b917915daaas34bd9aeaf1g8h8f77c32c5d1cea615e25f7721b8a9af0c08157c4f7c548aaaf293ec2dfd410425a4c8fa4314aeec302c8f82470098, Tp=Learning, startDate=09.ноя.2021 18:00, produser=Иванонв Иван Иванович}'
```

The problem is that the separator is " , " and the values also contain " , "

Comment: You can transform a object in a string with the JSON.stringify() and transform into an abject again with JSON.parse()

Comment: It is not possible to parse that String with JSON.parse(). You'd receive an exception because it is an incorrect JSON Format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this is actually an incorrect JSON-Format.

If you have the possibility you should quote at least the values like

```
var url = '{access="Свободный", superviser="Ромашкина Яна Витальевна", Spname="Классы Э-2, Э-3, Э-4", name="Эмоции и новая политическая культура", format="Дискуссия", project="Школа эмоционального здоровья", finishDate="09.ноя.2021 22:45", href="Doc?k=Ev&id=d50ed0941c79cf06b917915daaas34bd9aeaf1g8h8f77c32c5d1cea615e25f7721b8a9af0c08157c4f7c548aaaf293ec2dfd410425a4c8fa4314aeec302c8f82470098", Tp="Learning", startDate="09.ноя.2021 18:00", produser="Иванонв Иван Иванович"}'
```

It may be possible to filter for "key=" pattern but then still you have key value pairs in the url of the href-Property.